# How does Ubuntu change the fonts and icon theme for every user?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, useradd

I know how I can manually change the theme and appearance settings using dconf & the user shell themes extension for a single user, how to theme GDM using dconf & /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource, and how to enable extensions via GNOME shell modes, but how does Ubuntu ensure that all users have the same fonts and icon theme? I’ve checked /etc/default & /etc/skel for anything that might be relevant but it’s just $SHELL, .profile & friends.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Does it change significantly between Ubuntu versions?

Comment: The version is 22.04 LTS